# What is it called if a system is "in rest" until time $t=t_0$?

Tags: notation

I am a mathematics student, and am quite new to the whole control and system theory (haven't heard any lectures). I currently work with dynamic systems, but do not know the correct words for every attribute, yet.
I would like to describe a system as follows:

A system is in "**rest**" until time $t=t_0$ for some $t_0\in\mathbb{R}$ *if* the system response $y(t<t_0)$ and the state $x(t<t_0)$ are equivalent to $0$ for zero input $u(t<t_0) \equiv 0$.

I am quite sure, that there is a word describing this scenario. 
I know the term *causal* in terms of systems, but I don't think this is the word I need.

EDIT: To maybe make it more clear what i want:
I want to say "A system is in XXXX, when for zero input there is zero output." (~the system does nothing before any input is applied)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things to consider here. First of all, a non-causal system can react to input that hasn't arrived yet. And, secondly, there could be non-zero initial conditions that would contribute to the output signal without any input signal.

So what you probably mean is a "causal system initially at rest" or "a causal system with zero initial conditions".

Comment: Okay, so I need causality AND initially at rest. Thank you alot! Now I know what to google to go further!

Answer (score 0):

This would be *dead time*. You could also call it *delay*, i think.

Comment: isn't *dead time* the time the system needs to react?

So if for example the dead time is $\tau = 3$, and the input changes at time $t_0 = 10$ seconds, then the system response does not see react to the change of input until second $13$? i.e. the system response $y$ at time invteral $t_0$ to $t_0+\tau$ does not depend on the inputs made from $t_0$ to $t_0+\tau$.

Comment: Yes, you are right, i misread your question. Matt L. has it right.